# Null Exception ao importar o serviço no controller rest

Tags: spring-boot, restful, controller, services, repository

No exemplo a baixo, estou tentando fazer um Serviço RestFul separando totalmente o @RestController, @Service e o @Repository. Mas estou com uma dificuldade, pois quando tento utilizar o service dentro do controller ele a instancia fica sempre NULL, sendo assim, ao tentar utilizar a mesma dá um NULL EXCEPTION.

Obrigatoriamente tenho que usar o repository dentro da controller, ou posso continuar a usar mais separadamente ?

**Service**

```
package com.pokemon.tcg.api.Services;
```

import com.pokemon.tcg.api.Models.Type;
import com.pokemon.tcg.api.Repositories.TypeRespository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Configurable
public class TypeService {
    @Autowired
    TypeRespository typeRespository;

```
public void save(Type type){
    typeRespository.save(type);
}
```

}

**RestController**

```
 package com.pokemon.tcg.api.Controllers;
```

import com.pokemon.tcg.api.Models.Type;
import com.pokemon.tcg.api.Services.TypeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/types")
public class TypeController {

```
@Autowired
private TypeService typeService;
```

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody Type type){

```
    typeService.save(type);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(type, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

}

**Repository**

`package com.pokemon.tcg.api.Repositories;`

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.pokemon.tcg.api.Models.Type;

public interface TypeRespository extends CrudRepository {
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta a annotation @Repository na interface.